# Problem get ID (Angular Material - Firestore)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material

I am having problem when implementing a form in Angular Material, the `delProduct()` function does not work, neither does the `editProduct()` function.

The `getProducts()` function obtains the complete array (including the ID),

Adding a console log of the complete element to the `delProduct()` function gets the complete array, but without the id.

code list-products.components.ts

```
export class ListProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  productos: any[] = [];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayedColumns: any[] = [
    'cantidad',
    'nombre',
    'ubicacion', 
    'categoria',
    'subcategoria',
    'moneda',
    'precio',
    'action'
  ];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator)
  paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort)
  sort: MatSort = new MatSort;

  constructor(private _ProductService: ProductService,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.productos);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProducts();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.afs.collection('productos', ref=> ref.orderBy('fechaCreacion', 'desc')).valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    })
  }

  getProducts() {
    this._ProductService.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.productos = [];
        data.forEach((element:any) => {
      this.productos.push({
        id: element.payload.doc.id,
        ...element.payload.doc.data()
      })
      })
      console.log(this.productos);
    });
  }


  delProduct(element: any, index: any) {
   // const data = this.dataSource.data;
   //   data.splice((this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize) + index, 1);
   //   this.dataSource.data = data;
   //   this._ProductService.delProduct(element.id)
    console.log('ID', element.id)
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}
```

Code list-products.component.html (items are displayed normally, only I have problems with edit / delete functions)

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
          <mat-icon [routerLink]="['/edit-product/', element.id]">edit</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon (click)="delProduct(element, i)">delete</mat-icon>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

code product.service.ts

```
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore){ }
   
    getProducts(): Observable<any>{
     return this.firestore.collection('productos', ref=> ref.orderBy('fechaCreacion', 'desc')).snapshotChanges();
   }
    delProduct(id: string): Promise<any>{
     return this.firestore.collection('productos').doc(id).delete();
   }
    editProduct(id: string, data:Product): Promise<any>{
     return this.firestore.collection('productos').doc(id).update(data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading data twice. Once with ids (using snapshotChanges) and once without ids (using valueChanges).

I suggest putting an id field directly inside every document. It makes everything easier.

Comment: It was the only way to show the data. If I remove getProducts () or ngAfterViewInit () it doesn't work.
I can't get it to work.
Thanks for the reply

Comment: @alexisterzer well, at least use the same function, your `getProducts()`. Don't use AngularFirestore directly in the component. You can also do `valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })` to put the document ID as `id` in the array items.

Comment: @alexisterzer But putting the id directly inside the document helps developers in other languages (that don't have the `{ idField: 'id' }` available, that's angularfire-specific) handle stuff easier.